# How to find the distance travelled by a flight, if Flightaware is not showing correct distance?

Tags: air-travel, flight-status

I want to see the actual distance travelled by Air India flight 173 from Delhi to San Francisco. Usually, I would go to [Flightaware](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC173) to see it. But for 26 Oct, its showing 2 entries, and one of them (with 4 hour duration) is wrong. The correct entry of 15 hours is not accessible because of wrong entry.

What are some alternates to see the distance flown then? I tried finding it using [Flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ai173), but couldn't succeed.

Comment: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ai173#b6bf0e7

Comment: Look at the same flight for a different date?

Comment: @RoddyOfTheFrozenPeas but actual distance travelled is different on every day/flight.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid hmm it doesn't shows the actual distance flown.. Please tell me if you can find it

Comment: True but it gives you the ballpark value and is "close enough" for most purposes. What do you need this exact value for anyway?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @JonathanReez because it was probably the longest ever B777-3000 ER flight, with total distance of over 15,300 km.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Aviation.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better for Aviation SE.

Comment: As soon as it's the 'longest distance flown' AI will make some huge announcement, believe me.  In this case, it might not be possible to reconstruct the route if the ASDI was lost or unreadable.

Comment: Aviation.Se does also not consider this question to be a good question since it's more or less a support request. Therefore, I'm not going to migrate this question in the current form but close it.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you send a quick email FlightAware pointing out the bug. Given that they sell data to customers, I think they would appreciate it. They may be able to fix it quickly enough for your purposes or just tell you the correct distance flown.

[support@flightaware.com](http://support@flightaware.com)

Good luck!

Comment: I contacted them 6 hours ago, but haven't received any reply yet..

Comment: 6 hours ago? The lazy bastards! -- Seriously, most businesses have delays of about 16 hours between end of one workday and the start of the next; isn't it a little unreasonable to expect anyone to reply to a random email so fast that they may not even have arrived at work yet?